# Подключение socket.io к клиентской части

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Имею следующий код сервера(работает нормально):

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http, { serveClient: true });

var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Сервер запущен. Порт: ", server.address().port);
});
```

В index.html пробую подключить socket.io для клиентской части:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

И при это получаю ошибку: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ почекай тут, там описано, откуда берется файл

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно Ваш сервер не выдает скрипт `/socket.io/socket.io.js` как ресурс.

Необходимо настроить сервер так, чтобы браузер мог скачать с него этот скрипт:

```
// public это директория с ресурсами, которая должна быть видна снаружи
// в ней уже должно быть это - /socket.io/socket.io.js
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Либо, если это интернет-проект можно добавить скрипт ссылкой на `CDN`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
```